# Using NGINX on Kubernetes tries to load the assets with private IP rather than the domain

Tags: laravel, nginx, networking, kubernetes

So i'm using Laravel with Kubernetes and everything works great, except for the fact that when i access the website, it takes too much to load. I troubleshot it and i found out that some CSS and JS files are loaded using the private ip (the one that starts with 10: `10.244.xx.xx`)

I have no idea what's going on. Is it some kind of NGINX setting that messes it up? I am using the default NGINX Ingress for the cluster and i repeat: everything works great, except with this particular thing.

**Edit: It seems like the `route:cache` command messes everything. I don't know why.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i found it. It seems like i had to run `route:cache` between `config:cache` and `view:cache` on each pod deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Never use `secure_asset()` over `asset()` unless you know what it can do.
I had to replace all my `secure_asset()` with `asset()`

Answer (score 0):

make sure you got the domain right in .env file, in the root folder of your Application run:

```
sudo nano .env
```

find APP_URL parameter and configure it right, then run:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: I configured it correctly. The thing is that `route:cache` messes everything up and i don't know why.

Comment: I guess you may need to check if any resource was referred by hard coding their route on the server, check resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php file if you did use the default layout.

Comment: Thank you! <3 It seems like i had to use `asset()` over `secure_asset()` and force HTTPs with `URL::forceSchema()`